# Wrap DIV element between 2 DIVs by given selectors

Tags: jquery

Example:

```
<div id="id1">content</div>
<div id="id2">content</div>
<div id="id3">content</div>
<div id="id4">content</div>
<div id="id5">content</div>
```

I am expecting to show

```
<div id="tobeReplaceLater">
   <div id="id1">content</div>
   <div id="id2">content</div>
   <div id="id3">content</div>
   <div id="id4">content</div>
</div>
<div id="id5">content</div>
```

it doesn't mean to be every 4 childs, but it could be dynamic one, but the key is to encapsulate between id1 and id4, any expert know how to do it?

Comment: can u be a bit more elaborate with what you want ?

Comment: By given id1 and id4, I want to replace the content between these ranges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the 2 ids then

```
var from = 'id1',
    to = 'id4';
$('#' + from).nextUntil('#' + to + ' + div').addBack().wrapAll('<div id="tobeReplaceLater"/>')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mau70gf1/)

Answer (score 1):

Also you try with this, http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/j2v9852d/1/

```
$(function() {
    var all = $("div > div");
    for(var i = 0; i < all.length; i+=3) {
      all.slice(i, i+3)
      .wrapAll('<div class="wrapper"></div>');
    }
})
```